# multiple calls to GCE within 1 AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm a little new to AsynTasks in java programming for Android...

But, I see their point (let the UI continue while slow operations happen)

I have a GCE (Google Cloud Endpoint) API set up. To access it from the android app, it must be executed in an AsynTask according to what I've read.

My confusion lies with exactly what is the limitation within the AsyncTask before returning to onPostExecute?

The obvious use, is calling your API once.
So something like:

```
final myAPI.Builder builder = newmyAPI.Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null);      
builder.setApplicationName("mine");

AsyncTask<String, Void, com.appspot.myapp.myAPI.model.sample> publishAPItask =
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, com.appspot.myapp.myAPI.model.sample> () {
        @Override
        protected com.appspot.myapp.myAPI.model.sample doInBackground(String... strings) {
            // Retrieve service handle.
            myAPI apiServiceHandle = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder).build();
            try {                       
                myMethod myMethodCommand = apiServiceHandle.sample().myMethod();
                newthing.setthing(myMethodCommand.execute().getthing());
                ...
```

that last line executes, but also refers to the result already. I've read thats a no-no. Is that true? From [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/) is a quote:

> If you need to use an object that should be returned by the task, make use of the task’s onPostExecute override method. If you request a Lobster object from your API using an AsyncTask, and >then immediately try to use it in your next line of code (for example, Lobster lobster = new GetLobsterAsyncTask().execute(lobsterName); lobster.dance();), you will receive an exception. So, not only will your lobster “not dance,” it will “throw a NullPointerException at you”.

But it's a bit open to interpretation. Since I've never had an issue with the above use of the result, right away.

I seem to get intermittent issues when I added another call after the above code, calling other GCE methods within the same AsynTask - note, not using the result of the other calls.

```
myMethod2 meMethod2Command = apiServiceHandle.sample().myMethod2();
newthing2.setthing(myMethod2Command.execute().getthing());
```

**So is there a hard rule somewhere that says we can only make 1 call to GCE methods per AsynTask?**
Are the lines within the AsyncTask doInBackground() executed in sequence, or is it possible these GCE .execute() calls are made in parallel?
Before I rewrite a couple AsyncTasks so that they only contain 1 call each (and have a long line of onPostExecute() stacked up), I'd like to make sure I understand it...

It gets complex for me as I have a bunch of calls to make even a loop of calls. I want to make to my GCE method. So second question is: **Any suggestions for making a loop of calls to GCE methods?** I've also read the AsynTask can only executed once.

UPDATE: I have now just gone with the assumption that we can only make 1 GCE call per Asynctask. This makes for some interesting challenges for me, as I need to make a few in a certain circumstance in my app.
Anyway, what it turns out to be for me, is a loop of asynctasks being called, where each asynctask being called, ends up calling another loop of asynctasks within their onPostExecute.

ie. psuedocode:

```
loop
  asynctask 1 defined { 
    do inbackground {
    ...;
    }
    onPostExecute {
      loop
        asynctask 2 defined {
          doinbackground {
            ...;
          };
          onPostExecute {
          };
        };
        asynctask2.execute;
      end loop;
    };
  };
  asynctask1.execute;
end loop;
```

And the real challenge now, is that I need to know when they've all completed, before doing another operation.
I've seen a couple suggestions for an array of tasks and checking their status, or calling a function to increment a count.
Let me know if you have other ideas...

--- final update
Ended up going with a thread tracker count. Before each execute above, I increment 1. In each postexecute, I decremented 1. When the tracker's count is 0, I know I can call the final operation needed.

```
private class threadtracker {
    public int todo;

    public threadtracker (String grpid) {
        todo = 0;
    }

    public void add(int adder) {
        todo = todo + adder;
        Log.v(TAG, " threads:" + todo);
    }

    public void subtract(int subber) {
        todo = todo - subber;
        Log.v(TAG, " threads:" + todo);

        if (todo == 0) {
           //do final operation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: I've edited my answer based on nempoBu4's comment)

Here's some info on AppEngine Endpoints and using Endpoints in a Android client:
Udacity has a course covering App Engine it might be worth some of your time. 
https://www.udacity.com/course/ud859

You should read their Android client code though and see how they consume Endpoint methods in the client.  It's on GitHub.  The app is called Conference Central.
https://github.com/udacity/conference-central-android-app

**So is there a hard rule somewhere that says we can only make 1 call to GCE methods per AsynTask?**
I don't think so, I've made multiple calls to my backend from a background thread using endpoints with no problems.  The only thing I would worry about doing this in a single AsyncTask, is the amount of time it would take to complete.  "AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)" As per the Android Reference on AsyncTask.

**Any suggestions for making a loop of calls to GCE methods?**
I've set up an IntentService to consume endpoint methods in a background thread.  It's pretty straight forward to use, just follow the developers guide.  It'll put calls to the service in a queue, then once the service empties the queue it'll shut its self down.  You can set up a Broadcast manager to handle results.

Good luck.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Nope the links don't answer his question.  There are a few questions asked above.  My answer only attempts to answer his last question, Any suggestion for making aloop of calls to GAE? Which I suggest an IntentService.  The links just give some info on GAE and it's use in a Android client.

Comment: Jens did you even read my answer?  I've removed the word question above the questions.  But you really should read the passage you are commenting on.